# Installation via a network switch (Ethernet)

Tags: networking, system-installation

How do you install Ubuntu via a network switch (on mass)?

Do you need a certain program? if so what and where can I get it?
I will be using Ubuntu 13.10 network installer.

The reason I'm asking this is because I cannot find it in the install details. In the install instructions.

Also will I need a machine running Ubuntu or will Windows work?

Answer (score 0):

The network installer is not meant to install trough the network but "from" the network. You can boot a machine with it using minimum resources and it will download the packages from Internet during installation.

What you could do is install Ubuntu normally in one of the computers, and use [Clonezilla DRBL](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-SE/) to build an image of the installation. Then, clone the system to all the machines in the LAN using Network boot.

This assuming that all the machines have the same or very similar hardware. Specially regarding disks.